# iPhone - tabbar + view issue

Tags: iphone, view, tabbar

I am using a UITabBar control from library in one of my view (note that I am not using UITabBarController but the UITabBar control).

Now, I am adding two tabBar items to this tabBar.

I have created controller class for this view (.m and .h) files and used  delegates in the .h file.

In the .m file I have used the following function:

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)TabBarControl didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)FirstView

I have assigned tag = 0 and tag = 1 to respective tabBar items.

What I want to do is that, on click of first tabBar item I want to show a view and click of another tabBar item, I want to show another view.

So, in the above function I am checking that if the tag of clicked tabBar item is 0 than I will show one view else I will show another view.

I am showing the view as following:

Team1Scoreboard *tempTeam1Scoreboard = [Team1Scoreboard alloc];
        tempTeam1Scoreboard = [tempTeam1Scoreboard initWithNibName:@"UserTeamScoreboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

```
    self.cntrlTeam1Scoreboard = tempTeam1Scoreboard;

    [tempTeam1Scoreboard release];

    UIView *theWindow = [self.view superview];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [theWindow addSubview:self.cntrlTeam1Scoreboard.view];
```

Now the problem is that, when I click on any of the tabBar item, it will load the correct view but the tabBar itself will be disappeared as I am adding the view to window itself.

Please help me so that I can load correct view and also my tabBar itself is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TabBar is disappearing because it's a child of the view which you are then adding a new child to and the new child is sized the same as the parent.  Did that make sense?  Ok, look at it this way:

You have ViewA and ViewA has a couple of labels and a TabBar.  ViewA is managed by ViewControllerA.  In ViewControllerA you are creating an instance of ViewB and calling `ViewControllerA.view addSubView:instanceOfViewB`, right?  Before doing that, you will want to resize ViewB.

Try something like this:

```
ViewControllerB *viewControllerB = [[ViewControllerB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewB" bundle:nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 
                          self.view.frame.origin.y,
                          self.view.frame.size.width, 
                          self.view.frame.size.height - 40);
viewControllerB.view.frame = frame;
[self.view addSubview:viewB.viewControllerB];
```

Basically it should be close to what you are doing, but I'm setting the size to be 40 px less (whatever you need to remove the tab bar).

Comment: Hi Marcc,

Thanks, I was able to achieve the functionality properly.

But now the problem is that, the titles of each tabBar item are displayed at very bottom, and not visible properly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Is there any way you can post a screenshot of what it's doing now?